# How to share a pdf that is in a webview in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I have a webview and I call it an address that if accessed by a browser forces a download of a PDF, in the app I created I loaded the PDF in a webview, but I would also give the user the option to share this PDF by email, send To IcloudDrive, send it to the Ibook`s etc.

```
func asyncTask(parametros: String, id: String) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated.qosClass).async {

            DispatchQueue.main.async 
                let boletoURL = URL(string: "http://www.meusite/01_2017.pdf")
                print(boletoURL!)
                let boletoURLRequest = URLRequest(url: boletoURL!)
                self.webView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                self.webView.loadRequest(boletoURLRequest)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, create a singleton class as inventory of those PDFs. Secondly, save incoming PDF when you get the data which is in your `DispatchQueue.main`. Thirdly, share by email, send to iCould and sent to iBook are completely different functionalities. They are not such simple as you speculated. You have to implement them one by one. Please do some researches. You can find answers in Stack Overflow. Don't be lazy.

Comment: I know I need to save before sharing via email but I'm not able to pass this to the code, I'm looking for this for days right here and I can not find anything in Swift 3.0, if you can help me with the func thank you